# How to vertically center placeholder in mat-select-field in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, placeholder, mat-select, mat-option

I have placeholder in mat-select and I want to center it vertically. how do i do this?

closer to the bottom
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DHz3.png

**my codes**

````
                            <mat-select placeholder="Ödül türü seçiniz." [(value)]="PrizeType" >
                                <mat-option value="2"></mat-option>
                                <mat-option value="1"></mat-option>
                                <mat-option value="3"></mat-option>
                            </mat-select>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this with CSS

```
mat-select::placeholder { vertical-align: middle }
```

Comment: unfortunately this don't work me